# /etc/profile executing 2 times

Tags: boot, raspbian-stretch, startx

I have written a script to run automatically after login.

For that I have put it in /etc/profile as:

```
/home/pi/myscript.sh &
```

However, it is executed twice instead of one. Any ideas why?

VNC and SSH have been disabled.

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/profile` is the `system-wide .profile file for the Bourne shell`

It will run EVERY time you start a shell - it DEFINITELY is NOT intended to run programs on login, but to configure the shell.

Comment: The correct place to run programs once per specific GUI login is `~/.xinitrc`, but one had to copy the global template there first and change it because that's the file that also starts the window manager.